# Deleting child node in XML file

Tags: xml, powershell, namespaces

Say I have this XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <GPO xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings">
      <Identifier>
        <Identifier xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">{0afca021-554a-49cf-adab-2b6241895145}</Identifier>
      </Identifier>
      <Name>DefaultName</Name>
      <IncludeComments>true</IncludeComments>
      <CreatedTime>2012-08-08T18:20:05</CreatedTime>
      <ModifiedTime>2018-09-05T20:23:59</ModifiedTime>
      <ReadTime>2018-09-19T11:02:17.4750654Z</ReadTime>
     </GPO>
```

Using PowerShell,  how can I delete the CreatedTime and ModifiedTime nodes?

What's throwing me off, is the namespace issue with the GPO element.

Here's what I have so far:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content "C:\temp\x.xml"
$parent_xpath = '//GPO'
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes($parent_xpath)
$nodes
$nodes | % {
        $child_node = $_.SelectSingleNode('CreatedTime')
        $_.RemoveChild($child_node) | Out-Null
}
 $xml.Save("C:\temp\x-2.xml")
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the parent, Loop through each child node, and then remove from parent node. You can define parent by using "Node.ChildNode.ChildNode"

Wrote a quick function for you

```
function Remove-ChildNodes([xml]$FullXML, [string]$ParentNode, [string[]]$NodeNames){
    return ($xml.$ParentNode.ChildNodes | ?{ $NodeNames -contains $_.Name }) | %{[void]$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)}
}
```

And here is a working copy

```
[xml]$xml=@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <GPO xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings">
      <Identifier>
        <Identifier xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">{0afca021-554a-49cf-adab-2b6241895145}</Identifier>
      </Identifier>
      <Name>DefaultName</Name>
      <IncludeComments>true</IncludeComments>
      <CreatedTime>2012-08-08T18:20:05</CreatedTime>
      <ModifiedTime>2018-09-05T20:23:59</ModifiedTime>
      <ReadTime>2018-09-19T11:02:17.4750654Z</ReadTime>
     </GPO>
"@

function Remove-ChildNodes([xml]$FullXML, [string]$ParentNode, [string[]]$NodeNames){
    return ($xml.$ParentNode.ChildNodes | ?{ $NodeNames -contains $_.Name }) | %{[void]$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)}
}

Remove-ChildNodes -FullXML $xml -ParentNode "GPO" -NodeNames "CreatedTime","ModifiedTime"
$xml.InnerXml
```

Comment: Thanks man.  Appreciate the working copy, and quick response.  Works great.

Comment: The function breaks the XML formatting.  Any idea on how to keep the XML file formatted corrrectly?

Comment: Never mind, I was using $xml | out-file $path to save the output, switching to $xml.Save($path) works.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files, which can handle default namespaces and removing elements without looping. PowerShell can interface with .NET's [System.Xml.Xsl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl?view=netframework-4.7.2) namespace to run XSLT 1.0 scripts.

Specifically, in XSLT declare a prefix for the default namespace, here using *gpo*, then run the [identity transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity#TheIdentityTransform) to copy entire document as is, and pass empty templates for *CreatedTime* and *ModifiedTime* elements. So anywhere these elements show in document will be removed without looping or referencing parent tags. Plus, with this approach if you need to make other design changes to XML, you easily can do so in the XSLT script without touching PowerShell script.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:gpo="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- EMPTY TEMPLATES TO REMOVE -->
  <xsl:template match="gpo:CreatedTime|gpo:ModifiedTime"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFQ)

**PowerShell**

```
$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;

$xslt.Load("C:\Path\To\XSLT_Script.xsl");
$xslt.Transform("C:\Path\To\Input.xml", "C:\Path\To\Output.xml");
```

Comment: Curious @DobotJr ... was XSLT too intimidating?

Comment: Also, @DobotJr ... another beauty of XSLT is it is portable. I see you dabble in PHP. You can easily run this very XSLT in PHP and render same output and not be restricted to application layer code!